# AWS application load balancer Cname Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing

I've a Cname pointing to an ALB. When I hit the ALB DNS directly I get a connection but it complains about the SSL cert as seen here -

```
curl https://tek-q-appli.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/hello
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'tek-q-appli.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com'
```

So if this SSL error is ignored all is good as seen here -

```
curl -k https://tek-q-appli.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/hello
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>World</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the Cname pointing to the ALB, a connection refused is generated. I've checked the ACL and the SG's on both the ALB and the EC2 hosting the Docker running Apache, as seen here -

```
curl https://example.com/hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is normal and expected -- balancers don't offer an SSL cert for their AWS-assigned hostname.

The second suggests your DNS is incorrect or the update you made is not yet globally visible.  Curl should be showing you the IP address it's using for `example.com` and it should match one of the balancer's addresses each time you connect.

Use `dig` to find the IPs of the balancer's assigned hostname and those being returned for your custom domain.  Unless/until they match, that points to a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the heads up Michael.

I think the issue had to do with the httpd-vhosts.conf, as I followed this article

[Worth reading](https://locusinnovations.com/2018/05/23/aws-end-to-end-ssl-encryption-with-an-application-load-balancer/)

On end to end encryption behind an AWS ALB and the key points which got it going for me were -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
  </IfModule>
```

And

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
    # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
    #Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  </IfModule>
```

And plus - I had a local DNS entry for testing in the /etc/hosts file. In order to test the live domain using Curl, I needed to also remove the local hosts file.

All is good!